# Как получить данные из js используя return с библеотекой python eel?

Tags: javascript, python, eel

Есть такой js код. (cancel_status изменяется после некоторых действий) по идеи он должен возвращять в python после вызова 1 или 0, но возвращяет `<function _call_return.<locals>.return_func at 0x7f9f3c67feb0>`

```js
var cancel_status = 0

eel.expose(get_cancel_status)
function get_cancel_status() {
    return cancel_status;
}
```

Python код:

```py
import eel

print(eel.get_cancel_status())

eel.init('web')
eel.start('index.html', size=(200, 300))
```

Отправлять данные из js `eel.send_cancel_status(status)` не вариант, т.к. есть задача которая делается в python и именно её надо остоновить, а этот статус получается уже после выполнения задачи и следовательно не работает.

Почему возвращяется билеберда через return? Как мне сделать отмену выполнения задачи python используя js (на нажатие кнопки к примеру)

[**Полный код можете посмотреть здесь.**](https://github.com/zafross/Qwoq)

Comment: классный проект, кстати

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите раздел [документации](https://github.com/ChrisKnott/Eel#return-values) как возвращать/получать значение из `js-функций`.

Например, синхронным способом это делается вот так:

```
print(eel.get_cancel_status()()) # Вторая пара скобок
```